# How to gzip file with unicode encoding using linux cmd prompt?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, unicode, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have large tsv format file(30GB). I have to transform all those data to google bigquery. So I split the files into smaller chunks and gzip all those chunk files and moved to google cloud storage. After that I have calling google bigquery api to load data from GCS. But I have facing following encoding error.

```
file_data.part_0022.gz: Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 0. Error: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered. (error code: invalid)
```

I am using following unix commands in my python code for splitting and gzip tasks.

```
cmd = [
            "split",
            "-l",
            "300000",
            "-d",
            "-a",
            "4",
            "%s%s" % (<my-dir>, file_name),
            "%s/%s.part_" % (<my temp dir>, file_prefix)
        ]

code = subprocess.check_call(cmd)
cmd = 'gzip %s%s/%s.part*' % (<my temp dir>,file_prefix,file_prefix)
logging.info("Running shell command: %s" % cmd)
code = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
code.communicate()
```

Files are successfully splitted and gziped (file_data.part_0001.gz, file_data.part_0002.gz, etc..) but when I try to load these files to bigquery it throws above error. I understand that was encoding issue.
Is there any way to encoding files while split and gzip operation? or we need to use python file object to read line by line and do unicode encoding and write it to new gzip file?(pythonic way)

Answer (score -1):

**Reason**:

> **Error: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered**

Clearly states you have a unicode (`UTF-16`) tab character there which cannot be decoded.
BigQuery service only supports `UTF-8` and latin1 text encodings. So, the file is supposed to be `UTF-8` encoded.

---

**Solution**: I haven't tested it. Use the `-a` or `--ascii` flag with `gzip` command. It'll be decoded ok by bigquery.